# Regex matches during look behind

Tags: java, regex

I am using the regex below to match strings; I was expecting the following results

Regex `^.*(?<!abc)(?<!def)(?<!ghi).xyz.co.*`

Not Match

```
    ghi.xyz.org
    ghi-hipqr.xyz.org
    abc-hipqr.xyz.org
```

Match

```
qrs.xyz.org
qrs-hipqr.xyz.org
```

However, `ghi-hipqr.xyz.org` is matching the regex (it shouldn't have since there is a look behind for the string ghi which is present in the string.
How can I fix it?

Comment: A lookbehind does not look for its pattern match anywhere to the left of the current location, it looks for it *immediately* to the left of the current location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing because `ghi` is not immediately before `.xyz.` in your string. Java (like many more regex engines) doesn't support variable length negative length look-behind assertion.

You can use this negative lookahead expressions instead:

```
^(?!.*\b(?:abc|def|ghi)\b).*\.xyz\.org.*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lGNljG/1)

Comment: what confuses me is that it (correctly) doesn't match abc-hipqr.xyz.org where abc is not immediately before .xyz.

Comment: `abc-hipqr.xyz.org` is also matched as you can see here: https://regex101.com/r/lGNljG/3